# Как реализовать фильтрацию по всем полям модели (в том числе и в связанной модели) ASP.NET Web API EF

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-web-api, выборка, фильтрация

Появилась необходимость прикрутить фильтрацию к Web API. Использую ORM Entity Framework. Даны 2 модели данных: User и Role

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    
    public virtual List<Role>? Roles { get; set; }
}
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public RoleName Name { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Как реализовать фильтрацию по названию роли Role.Name, не совсем понимаю как грамотно выстроить запросы, поэтому обращаюсь к знающим людям, возможно еще подскажете как улучшить фильтрацию в WebAPI.
Вот текущая реализация:

```
List<User> list=new List<User>();
        if(userParameter.nameFilter!=string.Empty)
        {
            list.AddRange(_appDbContext.Users.Where(x=>x.Name
            .Contains(userParameter.nameFilter)).ToList());
        }
        if(userParameter.minAgeFilter>0&&(userParameter.maxAgeFilter>0
            &&userParameter.maxAgeFilter>userParameter.minAgeFilter))
        {
            list = new List<User>(list.Where(x => x.Age >= userParameter.minAgeFilter
            && userParameter.maxAgeFilter <= x.Age)).ToList();
        }
        if(userParameter.emailFilter!=string.Empty)
        {
            list=new List<User>(list.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(userParameter.nameFilter)));
        }
        if(userParameter.roleNameFilter!=string.Empty)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                _appDbContext.Entry(item).Collection(x => x.Roles).Load();
            }
            //вот тут не понимаю как отсортировать по ролям
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое "дорогое" при работе с БД - сами запросы. Поэтому желательно всю необходимую информацию из БД получать *одним* запросом.
Сделать это можно так:

```
IQueryable<User> users = context.Users;

if (userParameter.NameFilter != string.Empty)
    users = users.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(userParameter.NameFilter));

if (userParameter.MinAgeFilter > 0 && userParameter.MaxAgeFilter > userParameter.MinAgeFilter)
    users = users.Where(x => x.Age >= userParameter.MinAgeFilter && x.Age <= userParameter.MaxAgeFilter);

if (userParameter.EmailFilter != string.Empty)
    users = users.Where(x => x.Email.Contains(userParameter.EmailFilter));

var list = users.ToList();
```

При выполнении этого кода будет динамически конструируется `Expression`, который будет преобразован в единственный запрос SQL.

---

На мой взгляд, свойства-фильтры должны быть `nullable`: `string?`. И, соответственно, их проверка осуществляться так:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userParameter.NameFilter))
```

---

Я упростил условие с возрастом. Если максимальный возраст больше минимального, то он уже больше 0. Поэтому `maxAgeFilter>0` убираем.

Проверку по возрастам я бы сделал раздельно, чтобы можно было задавать их независимо друг от друга.

```
if (userParameter.MinAgeFilter.HasValue)
    users = users.Where(x => x.Age >= userParameter.MinAgeFilter);

if (userParameter.MaxAgeFilter.HasValue)
    users = users.Where(x => x.Age <= userParameter.MaxAgeFilter);
```

Да, эти свойства тоже `nullable`: `int?`.

---

Неясен ваш комментарий:

> //вот тут не понимаю как отсортировать по ролям

Сортировать: `OrderBy`.

Может, всё же имелось в виду "отфильтровать"?

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userParameter.RoleNameFilter))
    users = users.Include(x => x.Roles.Where(r => r.Name == userParameter.RoleNameFilter));
else
    users = users.Include(x => x.Roles);
```

Тут подразумевается, что у роли свойство `string Name`.
У вас указан какой-то неведомый мне `RoleName`. Разбирайтесь с ним сами.

Comment: Извините за некоторые неточности, очень устал, когда задавал вопрос. Очень грамотно и ясно все объяснили. Спасибо огромное за помощь!